# Is it possible to cin the name of a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, cin

Let's say I have some constants defined:

```
const int NUMBER = 5;
const int NUMBER_2 = 6;
```

Is there any way I can have the user input something like `NUMBER` or `NUMBER_2` and convert that to the value without having to `cin` using a `string` and a lot of `if` statements or a `switch` statement?

I have a lot of constants defined this way, in this assignment, and I'm not supposed to change them (it would take way too long anyway).

Comment: "The user input something like NUMBER or NUMBER_2 and convert that to the value" .....NUMBER is already 5, why would you have to convert it?

Comment: No, this is not generally possible. Also note that in C++, literal `const` don't typically exist in a single memory location after compilation, they're inlined in the places where they're used, which eliminates some potential tricks you could do with variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generic way to print out variable name in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622962/generic-way-to-print-out-variable-name-in-c)

Comment: I agree that it's not generally possible. However it is possible to automate this using a script that's integrated into the application's build system; then keep a single list of values and their "labels" (for a lack of a better word), then use a script to robo-generate a bunch of spaghetti code that consists of all the declared values, their labels, and the lookup code to map between the two.

Comment: So is there an easier way to do this other than having the user input a string, which would be either "NUMBER" or "NUMBER_2", and then doing a lot of if statements? (e.g. if (str == "NUMBER") x = NUMBER;) I mean a lot of if statements because of my code having a lot of constants like that.

Comment: Sure, store your constants in a `std::map<std::string, int>` and simply look them up with `find`. But they they aren't strictly constants. Constants are the wrong tool for this problem IMO.

Comment: You could store all the `const`s in an array and then you could display a menu to the user with options corresponding to indexes in the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Use input string as variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117238/c-use-input-string-as-variable-name)

Comment: I believe as well that you will most likely solve your problem with std::map. Still, to answer your question, you could do something pretty tricky and use the debugging symbols generated by your compiler to create a dictionnary of string that refer to address locations and then access the variable by its address. It is feasible, but most likely not what you need.

Comment: Note that writing constants in UPPERCASE is antipattern in C++