# Can cin be connected to a string variable?

Tags: c++, cin

For example, if I type `'a'`, how do I print out the value of the variable `a`, i.e. `"0 1"` ？

```
string a = "0 1"; string c = "1 1";
string b = "0 1"; string d = "1 1";

cin>>
cout <<
```

Comment: welcome - have you tried to see how to read input and use conditionals?

Comment: You mean like [std::basic_stringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)?

Comment: Do you mean entering the name of a variable at runtime? Variable names are gone* after compilation unless you keep them around manually.

Comment: like when it in output page, enter a letter, and can that output a variable that is already set right there? how to do that?

Comment: @TianleLi You are getting closer to a good description of your question. I would advise trying to use more than one sentence to describe the situation. We don't charge by the character. *See [Use input string as variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117238/) for an example of how someone else used a lot more text to describe a situation that might be similar to your query. (Personally, I would like to see even more description than that, though.) Value clarity over brevity.*

Comment: You want an [Associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)

Comment: Great minds [think alike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69156371/15261315) @Ayxan.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about some kind of instrospection like some interpreted languages have, but C++ doesn't work that way.

This is not the right way to think about a C++ program (or in any other compiled language), the identifiers in the source code really disappear once the program is compiled.

In other words, there is no automatic relation between the character entered (e.g. `"a"`) and the variable `std::string a` in the source code.

You have to manually do this:

```
#include<string>

int main(){

    std::string a = "0 1"; 
    std::string b = "0 1";
    std::string c = "1 1";
    std::string d = "1 1";
    
    char x; std::cin >> x;
    switch(x){
      case 'a': std::cout << a << std::endl; break;
      case 'b': std::cout << b << std::endl; break;
      case 'c': std::cout << c << std::endl; break;
      case 'd': std::cout << d << std::endl; break;
      default: std::cout << "not such variable" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: This code would be greatly simplified by using `std::(unordered_)map` instead of individual variables.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, well yes, however the OP asked (for example) how to print the value of the variable `a` when entering `"a"` as input, or the value of `b` when entering `"b"`, etc. The question is misguided probably, the point is to show that the answer to this question requires a introspection that is complicated very ad hoc and that there is no automatic way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you're not looking for a [map](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    map<string, string> m;

    m.insert(pair<string, string>("a", "0 1"));
    m.insert(pair<string, string>("b", "0 1"));
    m.insert(pair<string, string>("c", "1 1"));
    m.insert(pair<string, string>("d", "1 1"));

    // Or just:
    // map<string, string> m = {
    //   {"a", "0 1"}, {"b", "0 1"},
    //   {"c", "1 1"}, {"d", "1 1"}
    // };

    string user_choice = "a";

    cout << "Which letter?" << endl;
    cin >> user_choice;
    cout << "For " << user_choice << ": " 
         << m.at(user_choice) << endl;
}
```

A `std::map` does exactly what it says. It maps values of one type to another, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do, and it does so without using variable names, which as others have pointed out, are discarded after compilation.

There are then all sorts of useful things that can be done to a map using the functions provided in the Standard Template Library.